# What is the meaning of 'unlikely to comply to preserve'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw the translation of 'unlikely to comply to preserve' and I don't understand why it means 'likely preserve' and not vice versa. Could you clarify it?

> The newspaper said Roscosmos has asked for medical records and video
>   recordings that would show the movements and health of the NASA
>   astronauts and that NASA was **unlikely to comply to preserve** the
>   astronauts’ privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nasa was unlikely to comply ...

Comply means to follow instructions or orders. Robocosmos had asked for medical records and videos, but Nasa is unlikely to give Robocosmos the astronauts’ medical records.

> ... to preserve the astronauts’ privacy

This gives the reason. It tells us why Nasa is unlikely to comply. Medical records are private and not shared with other people.